# How do I fix my Nether Portal exit in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there anyway for me to fix the Nether Portal in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Every time I exit my portal from the Nether, I always end up spawning in a totally different place.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you get always somewhere else in the **Overworld**, there are several things you can do:

- Always take a Compass with you (or find out by whatever method which way is home)
- Make a Map
- If you think it's a glitch/bug, try the same things in a new world - if all is OK, try resetting the Nether Portals (destroying them) and/or deleting the Nether data folder (don't ask me where that is 0_0).

  - If not OK, check for the problem on a different device or try looking for this problem [on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft%20pe%20bug%20nether%20portal%20sends%20player%20to%20different%20places).
  - Also if the glitch/bug/problem is also on other devices/survives through reinstallations, inform Mojang on their bugs page, if it hasn't already been done by other people.